# Make <li> selectable inside Panel-group and list-group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a function for generating a panel-group and inside this panel-group a list. Both are dynamically generated based on a Database. The generation process is working as expected and also the Result I get displayed is according to my thoughts. However, I´m not able to make catch the click event on a individual list item.

```
function generateOutputList (data){

$InfoList = $j("#output");
var output = "";

$j.each(data, function(i, item){
    output += "<div class='panel-group'>"+
        "<div class='panel panel-default'>"+
            "<div class='panel-heading'><a data-toggle='collapse' href='#"+item['info_id']+"'>"+item['info_address']+"" +
        "</a><span class='badge customBadge'>"+item['user_count'][0]['user_count']+"</span></div>"+
                "<div class='panel-collapse collapse' id='"+item['info_id']+"'>"+
                    "<ul class='list-group' id='items"+item['info_id']+"'></ul>"+
                    "<div class='panel-footer'><button class='btn btn-group-sm btn-default'>Alle benachrichtigen</button></div>"+
                "</div>"+
            "</div>"+
        "</div>";
});
$InfoList.html(output);
```

And this is the function that catches the Click on a panel and generates the list items based on an Ajax request:

```
 $j("#output").on('show.bs.collapse', function (event){

    console.log(event.target.id);
    var currentInfoId = event.target.id;
    console.log($j(this).attr('id'));

    $j("#items"+currentInfoId).html("");

    requests.getMemberNotRead(currentInfoId, function (userList){
       console.log(userList);

        //Here the <li> inside the panel is generated
        $j.each(userList, function(i, item){
            $j("#items"+currentInfoId).append("<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>" +
                "<span class='user_name'>"+item['user_name_last']+", "+item['user_name_first']+"</span>" +
                " <span class='user_mail'>"+item['user_mail_address']+"</span>" +
                " <span class='user_notify'><button id='notifyUser' class='btn btn-default notifyUser'>Nutzer Benachrichtigen</button></span></a>");
        });
    });
});
```

I´m not even able to catch a click on the Button inside the list items (id: notifyUser). Can someone tell me what I do wrong, how I have to setup the selecter to make this code work?

If I just take the HTML markup without information based on the Database, everything works. Hope someone can help me here.

EDIT: For testing I changed the li-tag to a-tag

Comment: can you make fiddle of it, then it will be easy for us to help

Comment: I don't see any (on-click) event applied to your button #notifyUser nor the li/a tag with class .list-group-item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.delegate()` method to attach events to dynamically added elements.
For example -

```
$j("#output").delegate("#notifyUser", "click", function( event ) {} );
```

OR following version of `.on()` method -

```
$j("#output").on("click", "#notifyUser", function( event ) {} );
```

Comment: .delegate() method will finally call the above mentioned version of .on() method. So one should use different versions of .on() method.